# Mariadb query to update * for json structure

Tags: mariadb

I have a json structure like 
{"items": {"itemA": {"id": 1,"qty": 5},"itemB": {"id": 0,"qty": 10},"itemC": {"id": 0,"qty": 3}}}

What would be the mariaDb query to update qty for all items to 0.

Comment: It doesn't look like a valid JSON, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=e14774ac987d1cc2603998918fca5fb4).

Comment: edited the json

Comment: One option is to use a stored procedure, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=9b02589757b0ccd763c786911e25847a).